# How do I change my code to save to a directory by creating a file

Tags: java, javafx

Right now my code saves to a specific file but I would like to be able to choose a file or create one. how would I go about doing that?

```
-package application;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

public class GuiControl {
    // Max number of pics.
    private final int MAX = 6;
    // keep track of num of pics
    private int num = 0;
    // the FXML button
    @FXML
    private Button button;
    // the FXML image view
    @FXML
    private ImageView currentFram;
    // The FXML capture Button
    @FXML
    private Button capBtn;
    // The FXML Image holder box.
    @FXML
    private HBox imgHolder;
    @FXML
    private Button clearBtn;
    @FXML
    private Button savebtn;
    // a timer for acquiring the video stream
    private ScheduledExecutorService timer;
    // the OpenCV object that realizes the video capture
    private VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture();
    // a flag to change the button behavior
    private boolean cameraActive = false;
    // the id of the camera to be used
    private static int cameraId = 0;

    // Array List to hold a label of image.
    private ArrayList<ImageView> imageList = new ArrayList<>(6);

    // Image field to hold temporary image.
    ImageView temp;

    // Image used to resize
    Image t;

    private Mat frame;

    /**
     * The action triggered by pushing the button on the GUI
     *
     * @param event
     *            the push button event
     */
    @FXML
    protected void startCamera(ActionEvent event) {
        if (!this.cameraActive) {
            // start the video capture
            this.capture.open(cameraId);

            // is the video stream available?
            if (this.capture.isOpened()) {
                this.cameraActive = true;

                // grab a frame every 33 ms (30 frames/sec)
                Runnable frameGrabber = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // effectively grab and process a single frame
                        frame = grabFrame();
                        // convert and show the frame
                        Image imageToShow = Utils.mat2Image(frame);
                        updateImageView(currentFram, imageToShow);
                    }
                };

                this.timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(frameGrabber, 0, 33, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                // update the button content
                this.button.setText("Stop Camera");
            } else {
                // log the error
                System.err.println("Impossible to open the camera connection...");
            }
        } else {
            // the camera is not active at this point
            this.cameraActive = false;
            // update again the button content
            this.button.setText("Start Camera");

            // stop the timer
            this.stopAcquisition();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get a frame from the opened video stream (if any)
     *
     * @return the {@link Mat} to show
     */
    private Mat grabFrame() {
        // init everything
        Mat frame = new Mat();

        // check if the capture is open
        if (this.capture.isOpened()) {
            try {
                // read the current frame
                this.capture.read(frame);

                // if the frame is not empty, process it
                if (!frame.empty()) {
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, frame, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // log the error
                System.err.println("Exception during the image elaboration: " + e);
            }
        }

        return frame;
    }

    /**
     * Stop the acquisition from the camera and release all the resources
     */
    private void stopAcquisition() {
        if (this.timer != null && !this.timer.isShutdown()) {
            try {
                // stop the timer
                this.timer.shutdown();
                this.timer.awaitTermination(33, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // log any exception
                System.err.println("Exception in stopping the frame capture, trying to release the camera now... " + e);
            }
        }

        if (this.capture.isOpened()) {
            // release the camera
            this.capture.release();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update the {@link ImageView} in the JavaFX main thread
     *
     * @param view
     *            the {@link ImageView} to update
     * @param image
     *            the {@link Image} to show
     */
    private void updateImageView(ImageView view, Image image) {

        Utils.onFXThread(view.imageProperty(), image);
    }

    /**
     * On application close, stop the acquisition from the camera
     */
    protected void setClosed() {
        this.stopAcquisition();
    }

    @FXML
    protected void captureImg(ActionEvent event) {
        if (this.cameraActive) {
            if (num <= 5) {
                t = Utils.mat2Image(frame);
                temp = new ImageView(t);
                temp.setFitWidth(120);
                temp.setFitHeight(120);
                for (int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) {
                    if (imageList.get(i) != null)
                        continue;
                    imageList.set(i, temp);
                    break; // Exit loop this way only the most current pic is
                            // set.
                }

                imgHolder.getChildren().add(temp);
                num++;
            } else
                System.out.println("max number of pics");
        }

    }

    @FXML
    protected void clearAll(ActionEvent event) {
        imgHolder.getChildren().clear();
        num = 0; // reset counter
    }
```

Here is where the save action takes place. Right now the images are saved to a specific file but I want to be able to run it on another computer. and pick where to save

```
//
    @FXML
    protected void save(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            File outputFile = new file("\\Desktop\\dipImages\\");
            for (int i =0 ; i < imageList.getSize(); i++) {
            Image temp = imageList.get(i).getImage();

            BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(temp, null);
            try {
                ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", outputFile + " " + i);
            } catch (IOException) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);

            }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: so the top code is totally irrelevant?

Comment: How about a google for `javafx filechooser save file` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `FileChooser` for a file:

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extensionFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPEG image", "*.jpg");
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extensionFilter);
fileChooser.setSelectedExtensionFilter(extensionFilter);
File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(button.getScene().getWindow());
if (file != null) {
    // save to file
}
```

or a `DirectoryChooser` to select a directory. You should use the `File` constructor that takes a parent `File` as parameter btw.

```
DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
File directory = directoryChooser.showDialog(button.getScene().getWindow());
if (directory != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.getSize(); i++) {
        File file = new File(directory, i+".jpg");
        // save image to file
    }
}
```